# JavaScript get data from Firebase fail

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my own firebase structure.
I want to get the particular data in firebase, for example: win. I get an error message for it. I have no idea to handle those particular id that create with firebase.

[image: screenshot]

This my JavaScript code. When I run the program,the browser told me that the problem is in line 17.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please replace both pictures of text with the actual text. For the JOSN, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for changes on child nodes, or you can fetch a node on demand. [See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

Listen for value events

> ```
> var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
> starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
>   updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
> });
> ```

or read data on demand

> ```
> var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
> return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
>   var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
>   // ...
> });
> ```